# Emit a socketio event from rabbitmq consuming loop

Tags: python, multithreading, socket.io, rabbitmq, eventemitter

I have a nodejs server that is publishing data in rabbit mq and a python server consuming that data and when it gets the data i want to emit it to a flutter app using socket io here is my take on it but i m having some problems , the event is not emiting in the loop of the rabbitmq even , i tried to run rabbit mq and socketio server in seperate threads and pass the data between them with a queue but it didnt work because the send_message function blocks the socketio thread even tho im running it as a background task

```
import socketio
import pika
import threading
from queue import Queue
import eventlet
queue = Queue()

#rabbit mq consuming
def listen_to_queue():
    parameters = pika.URLParameters('amqp://localhost:5672')
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    channel = connection.channel()
    exchange_name = 'test1'
    channel.exchange_declare(exchange=exchange_name, exchange_type='direct')
    # Declare the queue we will consume from and bind it to the exchange
    queue_name = 'my-queue1'
    channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name)
    channel.queue_bind(exchange=exchange_name, queue=queue_name, routing_key='test1')
    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        print('Received message:', body)
        # send message to connected clients
        queue.put("body.decode")
    channel.basic_consume(queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
    print('Waiting for messages...')
    channel.start_consuming()
    connection.close()
    print("Rabbitmq close:") 



#socket io 
def run_socket(sio,app):
    sio = socketio.Server(cors_allowed_origins='*')    
    app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio)
    @sio.event
    def connect(sid, environ):
        print(f'Connected: {sid}')
        print("done")
    
    @sio.event
    def disconnect(sid):
        print(f'Disconnected: {sid}')
        #start the server       

    @sio.start_background_task
    def send_message():
        while True:
            # check if there are any messages in the queue
            if not queue.empty():
                # get the message from the queue
                message = queue.get()
                print(message)
                # emit the message to all connected clients
                sio.emit(event="hello", data=message)
                print(message)
    port = 3333
    print('Server started on port 3333')
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', port)), app)
 
       



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # start the SocketIO server

    Rabbit_thread = threading.Thread(target=listen_to_queue, args=())
    Rabbit_thread.start()
    Socket_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_socket, args=())
    Socket_thread.start()
```